# How do I align the text in the text-area on bottom?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to align the text of this two labels on it's bottom, so the two values are aligned on the same height.
[image]

Sadly, I dont find an option like aligning it inside its own area.
gravity wont work. It has to be in xml.

Thank you!

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_euro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/feed_cent"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:text="23"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_cent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:height="35dp"
        android:text=",39 €"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the gravity to bottom like below.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_euro"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/feed_cent"
    android:height="35dp"
    android:text="23"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
    android:textSize="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/feed_cent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:height="35dp"
    android:text=",39 €"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack" />
```

And also you can try android:gravity="bottom" to the layout you have used to hold the both `TextView` and change the 2nd `TextView` `height` into `wrap_content`.

Hope you got the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set your  textview text bottom 
`android:gravity="bottom"`

or
if you want to set your whole component bottom

`android:layout_gravity="bottom"`

Answer (score 1):

To align the text inside a TextView to its bottom, you can use

```
android:gravity="bottom"
```

(inside TextView tags)